# Function Pointers Error In C

Tags: c, function, pointers

In a book, I came across the following question.
The problem which I am facing is, what is a function pointer? How does it work and what is the syntax for it's declaration.

Point the error in given code.

```
main()
{
    int (*p)()=fun;
    (*p)();
}
fun()
{
    printf("Hi..");
}
```

my first question is, What does following code snipet signifies?

```
int (*p)()=fun;
(*p)();
```

and second obvious question what is the error in the given code..??

refer to ionela.voinescu's answer for solution.. it is same as that written in solution manual..thnx

Comment: Almost all of the code is incorrect.

Comment: And why would you tag your explicitly C related question with C++

Comment: Read [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/840501/how-do-function-pointers-in-c-work).

Comment: How old is this book?

Comment: @Armin -- Implicit int has been deprecated and is now considered an error.  Besides fun() does not return anything.

Comment: OP -- To answer your "second obvious question", why don't you run the posted code through a compiler?

Comment: @Armin -- sorry, I misread what you wrote.  Almost all of the code is **in**correct.  Spot on.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`int (*p)() = fun` declares a pointer to a function that returns `int`, then assigns the address of the function `fun` to that pointer. `(*p)()` calls whatever function `p` is pointing to.

Problems with your code:

1. `fun` and `main` should have a return type. Your compiler might not demand it and assume they return `int`s, but you should give them one nonetheless.
2. You need to declare `fun` above `main`, or use a [prototype](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Function_prototype)

Also, `(*p)()` is unnecessary; you can just use `p()`.

As a side note, because function pointer syntax is relatively ugly, it's fairly common to see typedefs such as

```
typedef int(*IntFunc)();
```

which would allow you to declare and use `p` like so:

```
IntFunc p = fun;
p();
```

Comment: In C standard, no arguments is represented by (void), () means number of arguments not specified.

Comment: @linkdd Thanks for the correction. That's what happens when a C++ dev answers a C question.

Comment: @slavik262 NP, another correction : in old K&R, functions with no return type are considered as returning int.

Comment: thnx a lot.. this was quite helpful and esay to understand..

Answer (score 4):

The correct code is the following:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int fun();
int main(){
  int (*p)()=fun;
  (*p)();
  return 0;
}

int fun(){
  printf("Hi..");
  return 0; 
}
```

1.

`int fun();` 
You have to declare your function before using it in `main`; Otherwise `main` wont recognize it. 

2.
`int (*p)()` : Declaration of a variable `p` which is a pointer to a function that returns `int` and has no arguments(or undefined number of arguments, depending on the standard). 

3.

```
int fun();
.........
int (*p)()=fun;
```

In order for this to work `fun` must also return `int`. Meaning when assigning a value to a variable this must have a type which corresponds with the declaration of the variable. When assigning a value to a pointer to a function that returns `int` and has no arguments the function assigned to it must also return `int` and have no arguments (or undefined number of arguments, depending on the standard). 

4. 
`(*p)();`
You call the function `p` which now points to `fun`.

Comment: +1 for including the header

Comment: Ah - so you do want to declare the functions before you use them. What book is this?

Comment: Test Your C Skills by Yeshwant Kanetkar..

Comment: Depending of your compiler flags, it may generate an implicit declaration of ``fun()`` and will report a warning. So you should declare it, but you don't have to.

Comment: ionela.voinescu - in place of int .. cant v use float or any other data type for function fun while declaring and defining it when the value is being returned..??

Comment: @DD24 - I don't know if I understood your question. Do you mean if you can declare and define `fun` to return `float` or other data type, but still use it the same way in the initialization of pointer `p`? The answer is yes, in this case. The compiler will warn you with `initialization from incompatible pointer type` when assigning the address of `fun` to `p`, but it will compile without errors. The problem appears if you use the value returned by `fun`. Even if you return a `float` value, in `main` after the execution of `p`, the return value will be interpreted as `int`.

Answer (score 1):

fun is name of the the function itself.

```
int (*p)()
```

is the definition of the function pointer like 'int a' is the definition of an integer.

int * is the pointer itself, () means it is a pointer to a function.

```
(*p)();
```

This is the execution of the function of the function pointer p, i.e. p is assigned to the function fun, which is executed by calling the content of the pointer p, thus (*p)();

Comment: -thnx for your help.. plz assure me if got the ryt concept..
int(*p)();  is the declaration of function pointer.. by writing int(*p)()=fun ..we are assigning the address of first statment of function defination to pointer p.. and in the next statment (*p)() we are executing the function using the address of first statmnet of the function defination stored by the function pointer p...
plz tell me .. if i am correct.. and this is what you wanted to explain me...???

Comment: @DD24 I dont think that function pointer would point first statement of function. This link may help you for certain extent http://stackoverflow.com/questions/597292/where-exactly-do-function-pointers-point . If you cant find any concrete solution, you can post it as separate question.

Comment: Michel -thnx bro .. the link was helpful...thnx a lot

Comment: @DD24: yes you got it right. However the first statement pointer is more or less the same as the 'entry point' of the function.