# Is type punning a function pointer undefined behaviour?

Tags: c

```
int test(){ return 5; }

int main(){
 int *p = (int*)(test);
 // read generated instructions of `test` 4 byte at a time. 

 return 0;
}
```

Assume I want to read the generated instructions of the function `test()` at runtime.
Also assume all instructions are `int` sized.

I know type punning with different data types cause `undefined behaviour`.

But what about the above case and type punning start of a function to an `int*`? Is this still UB? I'm not executing the function, just reading its bytes.

If it is UB then what's the proper way of accomplishing this?

#### Edit

Maybe this?

```
int buffer[/*size*/];
memcpy(buffer, test, /*size*/);
// Use the buffer.
```

Comment: Problem 1: type punning is UB due to the strict aliasing rule. The exception to that rule is casting to a `char *`. So you could cast to `char *` and then read four bytes at a time, and reassemble them into an `int`. Problem 2: converting a function pointer to an object pointer is not well defined. In other words, code is not necessarily accessible as data. This could be due to memory protections: code could be in execute-only memory (although typically it's read/execute, and only writing is prohibited). Or the code could be in an entirely separate address space, as with Harvard architectures.

Comment: @user3386109 Just wanted to clarify, my `edit` would fix the UB with type punning correct? We can also use `malloc` and move the data to the heap, return `void *` then cast it to an `int *` which also works without UB on type punning?

Comment: Yes, using `memcpy` to make a copy (with or without using `malloc` to allocate the buffer) avoids the type punning problem. But using `memcpy` doesn't avoid the second problem. By passing `test` to `memcpy` you're still converting a function pointer to an object pointer.

Comment: @user3386109 thanks. malloc returns a `void*`, so it would be ok to later  type cast that `void*` to any other type? that won't cause UB?

Comment: Yes, it's ok to use the pointer returned by `malloc` as a pointer to any object type. And converting to the correct pointer type doesn't even need a cast. The only thing you can't do is something like `void *mem = malloc(8); int *iptr = mem; double *dptr = mem;` That's UB because you've aliased the memory with two different pointer types, even though there are no casts.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Strictly speaking, the conversion is not defined. You'll *probably* be able to read the instructions, but it's non-portable, and there is no guarantee it's useful even when it works (e.g. if the function [is implemented with a trampoline](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/oldnewthing/20170807-00/?p=96766), you'd just see the tiny bit of redirecting code, and you'd have to parse it to follow it to the "real" location). You can read more in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22255406/364696) to [Where exactly do function pointers point?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/597292/364696).

Point is, yes, you can probably do this (ignoring the C standard, which has nothing to say about the low-level assembly implementing the function), but it may take a lot of work to make it useful and reliable for any given system.

Comment: Now that I think about it, Union or memcpy won't make any difference here. I still need a way to point to that region of memory and read it. Seems like there is no other way of doing this?

Comment: @Dan: I mean, you could just read the data (on most architectures) and it would work (even though it violates the standard). `memcpy` would read the instructions out into alternate storage just fine, typically. But this is also so far beyond what the standard covers that it's definitionally undefined (the standard doesn't define the reading of raw machine code like this at all), even if, practically speaking, it will work in a highly non-portable fashion.

Comment: But then how do emulators work, there has to be a way for them to do this, read instructions and emulate.

Comment: @Dan: Emulators read the instructions to be emulated *as data*.  An emulator has no need to ever interpret its *own* code as data.

Comment: @Dan: Emulators aren't reading their *own* source code, they're treating some other executable as raw data. They need to be able to parse the executable format, interpret (or rewrite to native code) the instructions, etc. The "rewrite to native code" bit does mean they can write out new code, seal it and mark it executable, then execute it raw, but that's a ridiculous amount of work, and basically nothing but an emulator or debugger needs to do it.

Comment: yes that's right, they load it to heap and parse it, but still, i feel like there has to be a way for an executable to read its own content.

Comment: @Dan: Yeah, you can do it exactly the way you proposed. It's just not C standard. The emulators that do similar terrible things aren't C standard. The C standard targets a virtual machine, not any specific architecture, and doesn't know about raw machine instructions. If you're dealing with the raw machine instructions, you're not writing standard C anymore, it's C mixed with machine native stuff. I strongly suspect you've got [an XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/66377/322040) here, but you also seem to think what you're doing is impossible if it's not standard C, which is wrong.

Comment: It's not impossible, but I just want to avoid UB as much as possible. a lot of UB operation actually work :D most times , I have made an edit using `memcpy` which might do the trick?

Comment: @Dan: Yeah, you can't avoid it. The `memcpy` seems fine, assuming the architecture/ABI in question doesn't do weird/terrible things (e.g. implementing run-time implementation selection by using a trampoline that rewrites the caller's machine code on first call, which would make you get the trampoline code, not the code it eventually calls out to), but you're going to have to get over the fear of UB; the instant you do *anything* to interact with the realized, compiled code aside from "run it", you're in undefined behavior territory.

Comment: FYI, C 2018 6.3.2.3 7 says a pointer to an object type may be converted to a pointer to a different object type, and that and other paragraph have some other statements relevant to such conversions. 6.3.2.3 8 says a pointer to a function of one type may be converted to a pointer to a function of another type. Nothing in the C standard says anything about conversions from pointers to functions to pointers to objects, so this is undefined by omission, per C 2018 4 2. That said, if one is converting function pointers, it is likely better to convert to `unsigned char *` rather than `int *`.

Comment: Also, on some systems, a function pointer may be the address of a descriptor that has, say, the address of the function entry point and a bit mask about registers to save or other information. So converting it to an `unsigned char *` will not yield a pointer to the instructions of the function.

Comment: @EricPostpischil: Yar, that descriptor issue is another option for fun problems. Point is, you're going to need architecture-specific code no matter what; in some cases, that architecture-specific code will be "simple" (can read the raw data out by undefined type-punning, or bypass type-punning, but it'll still be UB), in others, you'll have a few steps to take to find the "real" function instructions. But no matter what you do, the C standard isn't going to help you, it's just not concerned with this sort of thing.